# Hibernate 6 @Type annotation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jakarta-migration

I upgraded to Springboot 3.0 and in my hibernate entity class has something like:

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false, updatable = true, name = "accounts") 
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;
```

But I'm getting the exception 'Cannot resolve method 'type' since upgrading to Springboot 3.0 and moving to Jakarta persistence.

I need a replacement for com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer:

I had to use the lib:

```
<groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId> 
<artifactId>hibernate-types-60</artifactId>
```

and in the entity:

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false, updatable = true, name = "accounts") 
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;
```

Comment: Strange, I get error when I try this

Type mismatch.
Required:
KClass<out UserType<*>!>
Found:
KClass<JsonBinaryType>

Comment: I had something similar until I updated my maven dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

In Hybernate 6, new features have been added like the `SqlTypes.JSON`. So, you could have "jsonb" in your field like this:

```
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb") 
private ArrayList<Account> accounts;
```

Comment: I've been finding JSONb types are difficult to query against. Hibernate doesnt make it easy, basically forcing raw query types unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

In Hibernate 6, the mapping annotations are much more typesafe. You're usually required to specify `Class` references instead of stringly-typed names.

Comment: Thanks for the added color around the new change ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If you want to model JSON, I would suggest you to use `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)` which is how you model JSON with plain Hibernate ORM Core. Also see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-mapping-json