# Migrating to Hibernate 6 @Type annotation not working for boolean

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-6.x

I upgraded spring boot to 3.x which in turn upgrades Hibernate from 5 to 6 and spring 6.

In previous versions we were using `@Type` annotation which converts db column from String (Y or N) to java boolean value.

```java
    @Column(name = "IS_SPECIAL")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean isSpecial;
```

The problem I am now facing is that there's a syntax error that reads:

> Cannot resolve method 'type'

The annotation doesn't accept a string value either.

I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74966830/hibernate-6-type-annotation) and it's not helping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alright people. Making it easy for the those from future who run into same problem.

Taking the answer from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-boolean)

`@Type(type = "yes_no")` can be replaced with `@Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)`

```
@Column(name = "IS_SPECIAL")
@Convert(converter = org.hibernate.type.YesNoConverter.class)
private Boolean isSpecial;
```