# Spring boot upgrade from 2.6.9 to 2.7.4 causing boolean to be taken as BIT instead of CHAR during querying DB when value is null

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

```
@Type(type = "yes_no")
private Boolean xyz;
```

I've upgraded spring boot from 2.6.9 to 2.7.4

It's now causing "Error - dataresourceexception - Invalid Number ORA-01722" when the value of xyz is null.

When analyzed by enabling TRACE level logs for sql. I found that the boolean is considered as BIT when it's null due to some reason and causing the Invalid Number exception. It used to be taken as CHAR before the upgrade.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this and what's the root cause for this issue ?

Note: I cannot set the value of xyz as false when it's null.

Comment: if you upgrade to spring boot 3 there will be more issues, here is example solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/75996531/175554